# Unmerge XML files, is it possible?

Tags: xml, merge

I am using this scirpt, http://web.archive.org/web/20160809092524/http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT, to merge three xml files (f1.xml, f2.xml, f3.xml). the code works perfectly. I first merge f1.xml, f2.xml, then, the resulted file is merged with f3.xml.

now, I want to unmerge F3.xml and merge another file f4.xml, how can I do it please?

thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Keep a copy of (x1 + x2) for later use, or merge (x1 + x2) again.

Depending on how the merge worked, unmerging might be impossible without doing something silly like using a second script that deletes elements by re-reading x3.

Comment: thank you a lot for your response Dave, f1, f2 and f3 presents three blocs of a html page. when the page is running, only the third block (f3) will be changed by another bloc (f4). I don't want to merge f1 and f2 again to keep values already entred by the user